# Combining two Excel sheets

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I ship a lot of items to a lot of stores and I have two Excel sheets. I have one sheet showing how many items I have **shipped** to each store and another sheet showing how many I have **sold** in each store. The problem is I need to link them together (should have been done in the beginning but oh well...). I have about 547 stores I have shipped to and and about 450 stores I have sold items in. So not every store shipped to has items sold to but the store ID is unique and doesnt duplicate itself, except in each sheet.

So I have

**Sheet 1: Lists of stores with quantity of items shipped**

```
StoreID | qty-item1-shipped | qty-item2-shipped | qty-item3-shipped
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   4564 |                45 |                56 |                34
```

**Sheet 2: Lists of stores with quantity of items sold**

```
StoreID | qty-item1-sold | qty-item2-sold | qty-item3-sold
----------------------------------------------------------
   4564 |             35 |             46 |             24
```

I really should know this it's quite basic but its driving me nuts... the end results should be

```
       |       | Qty Shipped | Qty Sold
---------------------------------------
Store1 | item1 |          45 |       35
Store1 | item2 |          46 |       56
Store2 | item1 |          65 |        4
Store2 | item2 |          25 |       14
```

Now I should be using an access database for this kind of thing but conceptually I'm missing a rather large basic piece can you help an idiot find his way?

Comment: You did not mention how you want to merge the tables (using some programming language?). Is it a one time job or will you have to do this regularly?

Comment: Can you group the "duplicates" on one same sheet together ? Because then it's a simple matter of using SUMIF. If not, that's another story because there is no identifier to separate two entries for the same store on one sheet.

Comment: hey, thanks for that looks a lot better. I was thinking of using access, but either that or excel. I dont think I can group the duplicates though I'm not sure as "store ID 23" might not be in the same cell.. unless you can do it without them needing to be in matching cell numbers...

Answer (score 0):

like Alexandre said you should use sumif

```
col A: store
col B: items (of store X)
col C: sum of item Y shipped (Y an item from store x )
col D: sum of item Y sold

before you can do that you should use pivot table to rearrange your tables
store1 item1...value
store1 item2...value
store2 item1
store2 item3
etc
```

Its not hard to do it with excel but with so many stores and a data so valuable I think its time to think of real database... find a smart kid to build an sqlserver express database(free)/ open source DB for you .... even if it will cost a bit... you will sleep better at night.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

On copies (just in case!) strip out `qty-`, `-shipped` and `-sold`.  Create PivotTables for each sheet using multiple consolidation  ranges. Drill down to their data by double clicking the intersection of the Totals. Shift the right hand column of one table to the right. Copy Paste Special Values each table into a single new sheet, one above the other. Move up the label for the right hand column of the lower labels to the other row with labels and delete the lower labels. You should end up with a 'flat file' suitable for pivotting again to show your desired output, or for entry into a database if the latter is really what you want.